# Python, I want to make list json.dumped But, error 'dict' object has no attribute 'dumps'

Tags: python

below is my python code

```
r = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&channelId="+CHANNELID+"&order=date&key="+DEVELOPER_KEY)         
json = r.json()                                                                                                                                           
items = json.get("items")                                                                                                                                 
videos = []                                                                                                                                               
for x in items:                                                                                                                                           
  title = x["snippet"]["title"]                                                                                                                           
  videoId = x["id"]["videoId"]                                                                                                                            
  channelTitle = x["snippet"]["channelTitle"]                                                                                                             
  cam_thumbnails = x["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["medium"]["url"]                                                                                            
  publishedAt = x["snippet"]["publishedAt"]                                                                                                               
  data = { "title" : title,                                                                                                                               
           "videoId" : videoId,                                                                                                                           
           "channelTitle" : channelTitle,                                                                                                                 
           "cam_thumbnails" : cam_thumbnails,                                                                                                             
           "publishedAt" : publishedAt,                                                                                                                   
           }                                                                                                                                              
  videos.append(data)                                                                                                                                     
print json.dumps(videos) # this code cause problem
```

I inserted 'dict' to 'list' and then called json.dumps() But, error was arised
error messege is 'dict' object has no attribute 'dumps'

What is problem?, and How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your variable is called json, as is the module json, don't call your variable json and the problem will be gone

Comment: if you have imported json module, since you're assigning a shadow name of `json` with result r.json(), json has become a dictionary. change `json` to other name and ensure you import json module, should work

Comment: @Anzel ok, Thank you, I solved this problem, good luck!

Answer (score 35):

Previously, you must have imported the json module, writing `import json`, which creates a variable in your namespace named `json`.

Then, you do `json = r.json()`, ie. you assign a new reference to the name `json`, which doesn't represents the *module* json anymore, but instead the result of the `r.json()` method.

Thus, you can't use anymore the json module using the syntax `json.function()`, because json is the result of `r.json()`.

To resolve your problem, you must change the name of `json` eg. to `json_dict` or anything else.